# How to generate training dataset from huge binary data using TF 2.0?

Tags: dataset, binaryfiles, tensorflow2.0

I have a binary dataset of over 15G. I want to extract the data for model training using TF 2.0. Currently here is what I am doing:

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

data1 = np.fromfile('binary_file1', dtype='uint8')
data2 = np.fromfile('binary_file2', dtype='uint8')
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((data1, data2))
# then do something like batch, shuffle, prefetch, etc.

for sample in dataset:
    pass
```

but this consumes my memory and I don't think it's a good way to deal with such big files. What should I do to deal with this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You have to make use of [`FixedLengthRecordDataset`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/FixedLengthRecordDataset) to read binary files. Though this dataset accepts several files together, it will extract data only one file at a time. Since you wish to have data to be read from two binary files simultaneously, you will have to create two `FixedLengthRecordDataset` and then zip them.

Another thing to note down is you have to specify parameter of `record_bytes` which states how many bytes would you like to read per iteration. This has to be an exact multiple of the total bytes of your binary file size.

```
ds1 = tf.data.FixedLengthRecordDataset('file1.bin', record_bytes=1000)
ds2 = tf.data.FixedLengthRecordDataset('file2.bin', record_bytes=1000)
ds = tf.data.Dataset.zip((ds1, ds2))
ds = ds.batch(32)
```